# Integrating Angular with MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I wanted to integrate Angular application with MVC application. After searching on google I found below two approaches:

1. Configuring Visual Studio to run MVC
   http://dotnetdetail.com/how-to-setup-angular-2-with-asp-net-mvc-5/
2. Developing Angular & MVC Projects separately & then integrating them.
   stackoverflow.com/a/43127291/3787891

I found second approach to be easy than first. But I am not sure about which approach is best to follow.
Can someone suggest me when should I use which approach?

Comment: If you are integrating AngularJS, it would be much more easy as you can easily install the AngularJS nugget package. But if you are talking about Angular 2.0 ( You need to fiddle around with npm to set up the typescript). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHuTL_eRjsQ

Here is another quick and fantastic video to integrate your application.

The answer to your question is based on the requirement of your project.
1) If you are going to import that component in another project or application the 2nd one is better.
2) If not you can just create or modify it in MVC project itself. 
3) Even if you create it outside and integrate into your MVC project, you have to modify that component as per requirement. so you have to think that way as well.

Please let me know if you require any further help. I can share you a document if the video is not working.

Comment: Thanks Amit for quick response. The given link is not working. But I got from your answer that there is no major difference if we choose one over another.

Comment: Please mark as answer if this is satisfactory. or let me know if you requires more info.